# Receiving click events from separate lines with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to receive separate click events from separate lines in a text field, and every time a certain line is clicked by the user, I would like to highlight it and have an event happen.

I would ideally like this to happen with dynamic text, and not have to break the text apart by hand. Using the htmlText property is an option, but I am unsure as to how to bind clickEvents to separate elements.

Where do I begin?

Comment: Are you ok with your TextField being `selectable`?  That is required for the answer below to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no ready to use solution for this. But you can make it yourself using a few things:

- set CLICK listener for the whole text field
- listen for click and check the `caretIndex` property
- use `getLineIndexOfChar` to check what's the line of the current caret position
- use `getLineOffset` and `getLineLength` to get the position of the first and last character of that line
- use `setSelection` to highlight this line

There might be some faster and easier way, but this is what works for sure :)

EDIT: decided to post the solution code, as I was wondering how exactly it works.. and it would be a shame to just leave it unpublished and make you do it instead :)

```
field.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTfClicked);

function onTfClicked(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace (field.caretIndex);

    var line:uint = field.getLineIndexOfChar(field.caretIndex);
    var start:uint = field.getLineOffset(line);
    var end:uint = start + field.getLineLength(line);

    field.setSelection(start, end);
}
```